# Geometry, inscribed quadrilateral and angles

Tags: geometry

[image]

How to find angle e?

I tried using sum of angles and sum of interior angles. But does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) Try a new diagram, this time with letters on the vertices, to make it easy to argue about it.

Comment: Well, I copied this from elsewhere. So cannot change it. Can you help, please.

Comment: A pity. As it is is very, very not comfortable to write about it. For example: the upper right angle, the one besides $\;e\;$ is also $\;38^\circ\;$...can you see how cumbersome writing like this is?

Comment: Sorry Sir! :-( can we take it as 38 degree triangle and the second triangle.

Comment: I've no idea what you asked, @Joe...

Comment: O.k  forget it. Thanks anyway. I know it is difficult without naming.

Comment: It doesn't look that difficult. It's just that your diagram makes it very hard to write an argument about it. Making a quick calculation I think $\;e=114^\circ\;$ ...

Comment: This probably is from a competitive exam. I tried writing it. But I cannot link it. I am very curious as to the solution. I realise that you are helping me.

Comment: Hoping anyone else will be able to guide me as to the 3rd angle of the second triangle works out to 28?

Answer (score 0):

The angle on the right is $180^\circ-38^\circ-38^\circ=104^\circ$ (isosceles triangle).

The angle opposite to that across the circle is $180^\circ-104^\circ=76^\circ$.

Then the 3rd angle of the other (also isosceles) triangle is $180^\circ-76^\circ-76^\circ=28^\circ$.

Now you have $28^\circ+38^\circ+e=180^\circ$. So $e=114^\circ$ in agreement with Don Antonio's comment.

Comment: Please explain how you got the second line. That is 180-104=76

Comment: If two angles are such that they are opposite in a quadrangle inscribed in a circle, then they add to 180. Each angle is half the intercepted central arc, and those two central arcs add to 360 (the whole circle).

Comment: Not to mention that a quadrangle  can be inscribed in a circle iff the sum of one (and thus both) pair of opposite angles is $\;180^\circ\;$ ...which is just what @coffeemath mentions.

Comment: I understood now. This precisely was what was bugging me.  Thanks both of you very much.